# Deployment of compute instances in PieCloudDB Database

Tags: deployment, instance

I deployed a Cloud On Cloud version of PieCloudDB Database on a private cloud environment with 6 nodes. When creating a virtual data warehouse, I noticed that the compute instance pods only appeared on 5 of the nodes. How can I make the remaining node also host compute instance pods?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, during the initialization of COC version of PieCloudDB Database, all nodes within the Kubernetes environment are assigned roles. The node with the "master" role is marked as "control-plane," while the other nodes are marked as "data-plane."

Compute instance pods are only deployed on nodes with the "data-plane" role. If you want to allow compute instance pods to run on the node with the "master" role, you can execute the following command to modify its role to "data-plane." Please replace "master_node_name" with the actual name of the node.

kubectl label nodes <master_node_name> role=data-plane --overwrite